# Associating 2 Apps together

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-xml

I have a project  “Abc12” which contains App “TypeYourName”.
Also I have another project “Xyz12” which contains a Service like “MySoftKeyboard”, which is NOT a library type project.

I’d like to **associate project “Xyz12” to project “Abc12”**, so when user **downloads App “TypeYourName”, App “MySoftKeyboard” is also downloaded with it.**

Any idea how can be done, if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this as separate .apk files. (At least I'm pretty sure you can't do this either in the Android Market or the Amazon Appstore. I also don't know how you could side-load two apk files from the same link.) Create a single project that has your app and also has the service.

It might make sense to put all the code for the service into a library project. Then you could have the service available as a stand-alone project and also bundled with other applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The best you can do is within Abc12, query the package manager for Xyz12, and if it is not present, prompt the user to download it. Make Xyz12 a service or define the proper intent so that ABC12 can access it.